# Angular list item title directive not working

Tags: angular, list, angular-material, angular-directive

I currently try to show a list on my website that shall display pictures with a title and description. I use the following code snippet:

```
<mat-list *ngIf="gallery && gallery.pictures && gallery.pictures.length > 0">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let picture of gallery.pictures ?? []" class="list-row">
    <img class="list-picture" [src]="getUrl(picture.id ?? -1, true)" [alt]="picture.name ?? 'Bild'">
    <span matListItemTitle>{{picture.name}}</span>
    <span matListItemLine>{{picture.description}}</span>  
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Now, the spans with `matListItemTitle` and `matListItemLine` display as if these annotations were not present. I already checked that `MatListModule` is properly imported. Also, Webstorm raises the following warning 'Attribute matListItemTitle is not allowed here'.

I expect that my list looks about as in the 'List with sections' example given [here](https://next.material.angular.io/components/list/examples).

Comment: check the material version in your package file matListItemTitle and matListItemLine are only available in material 15

Comment: You are correct! I still use an older version. Thank you for your help!